# How to check if an activity is active?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using an AlertDialog in an activity. But when I close the activity before the  dialog is displayed, the application crashes because the context of the AlertDialog does not exist. So , I wish to display the dialog only if the activity is active. So my question is how to check if the activity is active. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show code to clarify how you are creating the `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check the [isFinishing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) flag before showing the dialog. It returns true if the activity is finishing, false otherwise

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
  // show dialog
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `isFinishing()` or `isDestroyed()`

`isFinishing()` is supported from api level 1

`isDestroyed()` is supported from api level 17

Make use of it before showing the dialog